# How to prevent a SCNNode from receiving any kind of shadows?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, scnnode, scnlight

I have a spot light over a SCNNode (skull), I want shadows to cast only in the skull.

[image]

How could I prevent the other nodes (see node underneath the skull in the photo) that aren't the skull from receiving any kind of shadow?

Comment: You should use constant shading model for your plane.  
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/lightingmodel

Comment: If you ever found the solution, or if `@Eugene` helped, please post the answer for people in the future.

Comment: I haven't :( wish i would

Comment: @Sergio Have you had a look at the `Casts Shadows` property for the light?